# Infinite scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to get a div element that includes multiple items next to each other.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
    <div class="child">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**So the `css-styling` is working very good so far - but I'd like to make the `parent`-element scrollable infinite - so that the `child-elements` are kind of repeating thereself.**

To sum up: *After you've scrolled to the right so that you are able to see the last element (number "11") the next element that should follow if you keep scrolling should be the first element again (number "1"). The same if you scroll to the left (the last element (number "11") should follow)*.

I really got no idea how to implement a mechanism like this using jQuery or js. So this css-styling is all I got so far. Sorry.

**Note: ** I do not want to add new elements. I'd like the same elements to repeat infinite. (Just displaying always 11 elements)

However - any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: but if we think about *infinite* don't you think that it's not possible as the parent is fixed width and the content is infinite so the scroller width will be 0 (a fixed width divided by infinite) ... so how you will manage the sroller?

Comment: Is JS accepteable?

Comment: Sure vanilla or jQuery. All sound fine :) @kabanus

Comment: sounds more like you wanna use a slider, check owl-carousel if that's the case

Comment: NO. `I don't want to make use of any carousel slider`, etc. I want to use pure js / jQuery and implement it on this custom case. **So nothing like owl-carousel.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attached an on scroll event for example on parent, adding an element on full right scrolling. Every time you scroll completely to any side, the other side element is attached where you are:

```js
var counter = 10;
var childWidth = document.getElementById("child1").offsetWidth;
function checkEdge(event) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    if ( parent.scrollLeft == parent.scrollWidth-parent.offsetWidth ) {
        //Detected scroll to the edge of the right
        counter = ((counter+1)%11);
        parent.appendChild(document.getElementById("child"+(counter+1))); 
        parent.scrollLeft -= childWidth;
    }
    
    if ( ! parent.scrollLeft ) {
        //Left edge
        counter = ((counter-1)%11);
        if ( counter == -2 ) counter = 9;
        parent.insertBefore((document.getElementById("child"+(counter+2))),parent.firstChild);
        parent.scrollLeft += childWidth;
    }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent" onscroll='checkEdge()'>
    <div class="child" id="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child" id="child3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="child4">4</div>
    <div class="child" id="child5">5</div>
    <div class="child" id="child6">6</div>
    <div class="child" id="child7">7</div>
    <div class="child" id="child8">8</div>
    <div class="child" id="child9">9</div>
    <div class="child" id="child10">10</div>
    <div class="child" id="child11">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to add something similar for the `container` if you want it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. But tbh this is not what I'd like to implement. I want the items to repeat (elems 1 - 11) not just simply adding new elements to the parent div.

Comment: @Asker changed the solution - instead of creating new elements, re-use the old ones.

Comment: @Asker so to be clear, no element is actually created.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/oxg549mL/5/

```
var threshold = 50;
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("scroll",addMore,false);
function addMore(e){

    var div = e.currentTarget;
  if(div.scrollWidth - div.clientWidth -div.scrollLeft < 50) {
    var node = div.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    node.textContent = div.children.length+1;
    div.appendChild(node);
  }
}
```

or repeated version:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/oxg549mL/8/

```
var threshold = 50;
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("scroll",addMore,false);
function addMore(e){

    var div = e.currentTarget;
  if(div.scrollWidth - div.clientWidth -div.scrollLeft < threshold) {
    var node = div.firstElementChild;
    div.appendChild(node);
  } else if (div.scrollLeft < threshold) {
    var node = div.lastElementChild;
    div.insertBefore(node,div.firstElementChild);
   div.scrollLeft = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not really that what I'd like to achieve. Your just adding new items to the element instead of implement a repeating method :/

Comment: That's what infinite scroll means.

Comment: `After you've scrolled to the right so that you are able to see the last element (number "11") the next element that should follow if you keep scrolling should be the first element again (number "1"). The same if you scroll to the left (the last element (number "11") should follow).`