# How to set scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to generate a infinite scrollable carousel 
 with `11 items` that are always repeating each other.

This is the code I got from [Infinite scrollable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074920/infinite-scrollable-div/50075109?noredirect=1#comment87166853_50075109). It is already working - more or less.

But now I'd like to update the code with the function that you can modify the scroll level so that you are able to call the code with e.g `(child3)` and the child3 will be displayed in the middle of the parent.

So you should be able to choose which item should be centered in the parent element.
I really hope you could get my thoughts so far...

**Note**: I thought about using `parent.scrollLeft(child3.position().left)` but this will not work because of the fixed number of elements.

**Note**: The count of elements MUST be 11 so I don't like to add **new** elements just `appending / insertBefore` the old ones.

```js
var counter = 10;
var childWidth = document.getElementById("child1").offsetWidth;

function checkEdge(event) {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  if (parent.scrollLeft == parent.scrollWidth - parent.offsetWidth) {
    //Detected scroll to the edge of the right
    counter = ((counter + 1) % 11);
    parent.appendChild(document.getElementById("child" + (counter + 1)));
    parent.scrollLeft -= childWidth;
  }

  if (!parent.scrollLeft) {
    //Left edge
    counter = ((counter - 1) % 11);
    if (counter == -2) counter = 9;
    parent.insertBefore((document.getElementById("child" + (counter + 2))), parent.firstChild);
    parent.scrollLeft += childWidth;
  }
}
```

```css
container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent" onscroll='checkEdge()'>
    <div class="child" id="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child" id="child3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="child4">4</div>
    <div class="child" id="child5">5</div>
    <div class="child" id="child6">6</div>
    <div class="child" id="child7">7</div>
    <div class="child" id="child8">8</div>
    <div class="child" id="child9">9</div>
    <div class="child" id="child10">10</div>
    <div class="child" id="child11">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to develop it by your own? There are pretty good plugins out there.

Comment: Yes I'd really like to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to implement it by yourself, I would advice you to use same solution as you used in your `checkEnde()` method, but not by modifying `parent.scrollLeft` but by moving last or first element of collection to the other side of it. Like below:

```js
var counter = 10;
var childWidth = document.getElementById("child1").offsetWidth;
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
function checkEdge(event) {
  
  if (parent.scrollLeft == parent.scrollWidth - parent.offsetWidth) {
    //Detected scroll to the edge of the right
    counter = ((counter + 1) % 11);
    parent.appendChild(document.getElementById("child" + (counter + 1)));
    parent.scrollLeft -= childWidth;
  }

  if (!parent.scrollLeft) {
    //Left edge
    counter = ((counter - 1) % 11);
    if (counter == -2) counter = 9;
    parent.insertBefore((document.getElementById("child" + (counter + 2))), parent.firstChild);
    parent.scrollLeft += childWidth;
  }
}

function setTo(id) {
  var move = setInterval(function() {
    if(parent.children[5].id != id) {
      parent.insertBefore(parent.children[10], parent.children[0]);
    } else {
      clearInterval(move);
    }
  }, 100)
}
```

```css
container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.child:nth-child(6) {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent" onscroll='checkEdge()'>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child1')" id="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child2')" id="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child3')" id="child3">3</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child4')" id="child4">4</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child5')" id="child5">5</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child6')" id="child6">6</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child7')" id="child7">7</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child8')" id="child8">8</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child9')" id="child9">9</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child10')" id="child10">10</div>
    <div class="child" onclick="setTo('child11')" id="child11">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It moves only one direction (left), but I just want to show you a general idea, you need to find a detailed solution that will suits your needs. Maybe you will find it useful.